# building a python command by concatenation

Tags: python, python-2.7, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am generating  command passed to `python -c` like this

```
'python -c "import '+impMod+'; help('+module+'.'+method+') if \''+method+'\' in dir('+module+') else from '+impMod+' import '+method+' help('+method+')"'
```

and get output like this:

```
python -c "import os; help(os.path.pathconf) if 'pathconf' in dir(os.path) else from os import pathconf help(pathconf)"
```

even if i try

```
python -c "import os; help(os.path.pathconf) if 'pathconf' in dir(os.path) else from os import pathconf; help(pathconf)"
```

but don't know why I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any help will be appreciated,
Regards.

Comment: you don't need that `';'`

Comment: well thats not the case, please check the line further , i guess its when I introduce `help()` after `from os import pathconf`

Comment: Yeah python does not use those.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up statements and expressions. The `from .. import ..` syntax is a statement, and cannot appear inside an expression, but you are using it inside a `... if ... else ...` expression. Also, you can use newlines inside a shell string.

```
python -c "import os
if 'pathconf' in dir(os.path):
    help(os.path.pathconf)
else:
    from os import pathconf
    help(pathconf)"
```

To do that in Python, you might want to use triple quotes.

Comment: Oh, in your case help() will get executed twice if the first if block  is True.